# Oracle Contains failed working for phrase containing "not" word

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, text-search

I'm trying to search a phrase like 'not placed' in table, where col is indexed by "indextype is ctxsys.context"

```
select * from 
table
where contains (col, 'not placed')>0
```

Without the "NOT" word the search is working absolutely fine without any issues.

As soon as the "not" is added in the search phrase the below issue is thrown -

```
ORA-29902: error in executing ODCIIndexStart() routine
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-50901: text query parser syntax error on line 1, column 1  
29902. 00000 -  "error in executing ODCIIndexStart() routine"
*Cause:    The execution of ODCIIndexStart routine caused an error.
*Action:   Examine the error messages produced by the indextype code and
           take appropriate action.
```

I even tried to use escape sequence for the "not" word but it failed to recognize the "not" word itself

Comment: What does `where instr(col, 'not placed') > 0` say?

Comment: Try to wrap the search string using `{}` as `contains (col, '{not placed}')>0`

Comment: @Littlefoot this cannot be used as the col size is big and we need an index working on it

Comment: @Tejash This is giving results of records which has "placed" and negating the presence of "not"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`not` is a reserved word for the `not` operator. You need to escape it to search for this value with `contains`. Do this by surrounding it in curly braces `{}`.

It's also one of the default stop words. These are not included in the index.

This creates an index with an empty stop list. So it includes every word:

```
create table t (
  c1 varchar2(100)
);

insert into t values ( 'placed' );
insert into t values ( 'not placed' );
insert into t values ( 'something else' );
insert into t values ( 'file is placed in folder' ); 
insert into t values ( 'file is not placed in folder' ); 
commit;

create index i 
  on t ( c1 ) 
  indextype is ctxsys.context
  parameters (
    'stoplist ctxsys.empty_stoplist sync(on commit)'
  );

select * from t 
where  contains (c1, 'placed') > 0;

C1                             
placed                          
not placed                      
file is placed in folder        
file is not placed in folder  

select * from t 
where  contains (c1, 'not placed') > 0;

ORA-29902: error in executing ODCIIndexStart() routine
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-50901: text query parser syntax error on line 1, column 1  

select * from t 
where  contains (c1, '{not} placed') > 0;

C1                             
not placed                      
file is not placed in folder
```

But you probably want to create your own [custom stop list](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/tutorial_ILZT0N3FKVMEAY1HU8Z93ZL5J.html).

Comment: It fails if done like below -
insert into t values ( 'file is not placed in folder' );
insert into t values ( 'file is placed in folder' );

select * from t
where contains (c1, '{not} placed') > 0;

Result - 
not placed,
file is not placed in folder,
file is placed in folder,

Comment: Not is a stop word - you'll want to create a stop list that excludes this. Example updated

Comment: Thanks Chris! it worked. For further details on creating ctxsys index this link is useful - https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/tutorial_ILZT0N3FKVMEAY1HU8Z93ZL5J.html